# Weirds characters with PDOException error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, encoding, error-handling

I am running MariaDB on CentOS 7 with PHP 5.6.
Here is my connection string:

```
try {
   $connStr = 'mysql:host=server;dbname=mysql';
   $pdo = new PDO($connStr, 'user', 'passwd');
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $pdo->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
catch(PDOException $err) {
   var_dump($err->getMessage());
   die();
}
```

Everything works fine, there is no encoding issues except with PDO errors which raise some weirds characaters:

> MUH��/NU(~�03��D!71G� ����J����̜��*���+S��+S��N|5

How can I manage that?

Comment: Look for "black diamond" in [_here_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: The problem is that it happens only with SQL error messages. Data are corectly handled

Answer (score 0):

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` near start of html page